# Possible Masters degrees for a maths Graduate

Tags: soft-question

So I will be finishing my degree in Maths at the end of next year and was considering doing a masters in Maths combined with another discipline such as biology , Earth sciences , oceanography etc

I ask this question becuase I am very interested in the both maths and the natural world - and would like to incorporate the two in my masters. What masters degrees would there be which would in operate the two ?

In addition to this any ideas of the potential career prospects ?

Answer (score 1):

To name a couple of programs:
 
[The Quantitative Ecology and Resource Management (QERM) is a unique interdisciplinary graduate program at the University of Washington, designed for mathematically trained students interested in working on ecological or resource management problems from a quantitative perspective. The program offers M.S. and Ph.D. degrees.

Students receive intensive training in the application of statistical, mathematical and decision sciences to terrestrial, and aquatic ecology, natural resource management, biometrics and mathematical biology.][1](http://depts.washington.edu/qerm/)

[Mathematical Biology Research Program at the University of Utah
Program Overview
The Department of Mathematics at the University of Utah has a research group consisting of faculty, postdoctoral fellows, and graduate students, whose work is at the forefront of mathematical biology research and education.

Research in Mathematical Biology is in four broad areas: Biofluids, Ecology and Evolutionary Biology, Neuroscience and Physiology. The goal of this effort is to use mathematical reasoning and techniques to gain insights into complex biological phenomena.][2](http://www.math.utah.edu/research/mathbio/)

List of jobs from governmental, academic or private sector could be very long pending on what focus you went into since math has a lot of branches and science does too.

So what branch of science do you like to work in and what areas of math are you comfortable in?

Comment: Comfortable in Biology , Ecology and Evolutionary Biology ! And love calculus